# Non-resourceful routes in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing a signup form on the home page of my web app. The form has a `user` model and a `reminder` model, both Ember Data models.

When the form submits it POSTs to `/api/signups`. The back-end creates the user, creates the reminder, and sends an email. There is no actual `signup` record created in a database.

How can I send my reminder + user data to this URL using Ember Data? I'm able to embed the reminder in the user and thereby get all the data over in one payload, but I'm not sure the most idiomatic way to tell Ember Data's adapter to POST to `/api/signups` (instead of e.g. `/api/users` or `/api/reminders`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the inflector ( http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization) with something like:

```
inflector.irregular('user','signups');
```

That should force Ember Data to post to `/signups` whenever you save, but itll also fetch from that route as well.